# Group and count by age breaks

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

For voyages (Years, ships), how can I group and count sailors by age intervalles in standard SQL or MS-ACCESS?

```
YEAR    SHIP            SAILOR_AGE
2003    Flying dolphin  33
2003    Flying dolphin  33
2003    Flying dolphin  34
2001    Flying dolphin  23
2003    Flying dolphin  35
2001    Flying dolphin  38
2001    Flying dolphin  31
2003    Flying dolphin  36
2003    Columbine       41
2003    Columbine       42
2003    Flying dolphin  27
2003    Flying dolphin  51
2003    Flying dolphin  46
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT YEAR, SHIP, SAILOR_AGE,  COUNT (*) as `NUMBERS` 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY YEARS, SHIP, SAILOR_AGE;
```

It give me the number of sailor for each year:

Example:

```
YEAR |SHIP           |SAILOR_AGE  | NUMBERS
------------------------------------------
2003 | Flying dolphin| 33         |   2
```

How Can group sailor ages by intervalles

Example:

```
From 20th to 40th year's old  
From 40th  to 60th year's old
```

Comment: Why don't you use `CASE..WHEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single query using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.years,t.ship,
       CASE WHEN t.Sailor_age between 21 and 40 then 'From 20th to 40th'
            WHEN t.Sailor_age between 41 and 60 then 'From 40th to 60th'
            ELSE 'Other Ages'
       END as Range
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.years,t.ship,CASE WHEN t.Sailor_age between 21 and 40 then 'From 20th to 40th' WHEN t.Sailor_age between 41 and 60 then 'From 40th to 60th' ELSE 'Other Ages' END
ORDER BY t.years,t.ship,Range
```

Or if you want it as a single row using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.years,t.ship,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Sailor_age between 21 and 40 then 1 end) as Age_21_to_40,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Sailor_age between 41 and 60 then 1 end) as Age_41_to_60,
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.years,t.ship
ORDER BY t.years,t.ship
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `CASE` to specify age ranges in following:

```
SELECT YEARS, SHIP, AgeRange, COUNT (*) as `NUMBERS` 
FROM (SELECT YEAR
            , SHIP
            , CASE WHEN SAILOR_AGE BETWEEN 21 AND 40 THEN '21-40'
                   WHEN SAILOR_AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 60 THEN '41-60'
                   ELSE 'XX-XX' -- anything goes here
              END as AgeRange
      FROM YourTable
)x
GROUP BY YEARS, SHIP, AgeRange;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the values in columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR, SHIP, COUNT(*) as NUMSAILORS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SAILOR_AGE BETWEEN 21 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AGE_21_40,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SAILOR_AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AGE_41_60
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY YEARS, SHIP;
```

Answer (score 2):

As this - given the tags - most likely is Access SQL, you can go like this:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR, 
    SHIP, 
    INT(SAILOR_AGE / 20) * 20 AS AgeGroup,  
    COUNT(*) As [NUMBERS]
FROM 
    TABLE
GROUP BY 
    YEAR, 
    SHIP, 
    INT(SAILOR_AGE / 20) * 20
```

Comment: It works great but it is less clear that the *case when* statement for me!

Comment: Perhaps, but _Case-When_ is unknown by Access SQL.

Comment: I am trying to convert my Access db to sqlite db but I didnt found a free and fast working conversion tool...

Comment: Oh, then you may face troubles. SQLite is severely limited compared to Access, indeed regarding data types.

Comment: I need to convert my Access Db to a geographic database working with GIS qgis! (sqlite -spatialite extension)

Comment: OK. Then remove all the Access tags from the question.

Comment: I will keep an MS-Access version...so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to achieve that is to create helper table:

```
DECLARE @hlptbl TABLE(DescOfGrp VARCHAR(50), AgeFrom INT, AgeTo INT)
INSERT INTO @hlptbl (DescOfGrp, AgeFrom, AgeTo)
VALUES('20 to 40', 20, 40),
('41 to 60', 40, 60)
```

Then, you have to join data this way:

```
SELECT t1.[Year], t1.SHIP, t2.DescOfGrp, COUNT(t1.SHIP) AS Number
FROM TableA As t1 INNER JOIN @hlptbl AS t2 ON 
           t1.SAILOR_AGE>=t2.AgeFrom AND t1.SAILOR_AGE <=t2.AgeTo
GROUP BY t1.[Year], t1.SHIP, t2.DescOfGrp
```

Result:

```
Year    SHIP    DescOfGrp   Number
2001    Flying dolphin  20 to 40    3
2003    Columbine       41 to 60    2
2003    Flying dolphin  20 to 40    6
2003    Flying dolphin  41 to 60    2
```